# Git does not like underscores

Tags: git, composer-php, bigcommerce

I am trying to push a project that has a folder with an underscore in the name. It is a [BigCommerce Hello World](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-php-silex) app that uses 
["realityking/hash_equals": "dev-master"](https://github.com/realityking/hash_equals). The dependency is in 'vendor\realityking\hash_equals'. When I push the project, then clone it, the hash_equals folder is empty. When I run git rm -r * to delete the repository from Heroku, I get an error.

error: the following file has staged content different from both the
file and the HEAD:
    vendor/realityking/hashequals
(use -f to force removal)

I tried everything to delete it but I could not. I deleted the app, created a new one, deleted .git locally, started over, and I get the same problem.

Obviously, I should not use underscores in folder or file names, but this is an existing "Hello World" project that has been proven to work.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In the Heroku build log, do you see "Git submodules detected, installing Submodule 'vendor/realityking/hash_equals'"?

Comment: No, but there is a warning. WARNING: Your Composer vendor dir is part of your Git repository.
       This directory should not be under version control; only your
       'composer.json' and 'composer.lock' files should be added, which
       will let Composer handle installation of dependencies on deploy. Am I not supposed to push the vendor folder? I could not get it to work and I was getting an error saying that it could not find something in the vendor folder, so I took it out of the .gitignore.

Comment: This has _nothing_ to do with underscores. As Stephen suggests you probably have a partially-configured submodule accidentally created when you started tracking your `vendor/` folder.

Comment: "Obviously, I should not use underscores in folder or file names"
Whattt, there's nothing wrong about doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku uses 'composer.json' and 'composer.lock' to restore the vendor directory each time you deploy. This means the `vendor` directory should *not* be committed in Git.

If you commit those two files, [Heroku's PHP buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php#manage-dependencies) restores packages using Composer.

The directory is empty when you clone the repository because you must use Composer to restore them. Use the command [`php composer.phar install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install) to re-populate your vendor directory.

To remove the hash_equals directory from your repository, use the command [`git rm -fr vendor/realityking/hash_equals`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm), then commit.